# Mysql query to check any four words in the input string to match

Tags: mysql, regex, match

I want to get a query which can retrieve data if any four words in the input string match with the data.

For example if the sentence is "Match four words anywhere in the title"

I wan to get  all rows which matches any of the four words in this sentence.

Is it possible to do with preg_rlike

Please help

Thanks

Comment: So may down voted for this question. I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

Establish a FULTEXT index, then change to `MATCH ... AGAINST ...`, but do not use "+" since you are not requiring each word.